# Broken tooltip for question link with non-Latin symbols in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, localization, tooltips

If I put a link (from the browser) to a question with non-Latin title in the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?answertab=active#comment933098_286872), then I've got not URL decoded text with incorrect right border (in FF):

> [image: encoded tooltip]

I would like to see correct title here, i.e.:

> **Список строк transifex, требующих множественных форм**

Related [question in meta.ruSO.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3861/176217)